# Is it possible to do some sort of implicit loop with Twigs `{% image %}` to return all images in the directory?

Tags: symfony, twig, twig-extension

Considering that Twig has it's `{% for %}` loops and it's `{% image %}` sections, is there something such as the following be done with Twig to return all images within the `AppBundle/Resources/images/gallery/` directory? It would seem to make sense but I've not been able to find anything so far:

```
{% image @AppBundle/Resources/images/gallery/*.jpg %}
    <img src="{{ asset_url }} />
{% endimage %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is possible. Assetic just doesn't distinguish between different file types:

```
{% image '@AppBundle/Resources/images/gallery/*' %}
  <img src="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endimage %}
```

This will render all images from the gallery directory, no matter the file extension.

The same can be done with CSS and JS files via

```
{% stylesheets '@AppBundle/Resources/css/*' %}
  <img src="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}

{% javascripts '@AppBundle/Resources/js/*' %}
  <img src="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endjavascripts %}
```

Comment: Thank you! That works for what I need....so there's no way though to conditionally return certain filetypes though?

Comment: I unticked the answer just to avoid confusion for others.... it works in `dev` however I transferred it over to `prod` and it turns out that this implicit loop can't work in production